# Chunking a specific word in nltk python

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, chunking

Observe the short example:

For example:

```
tagged = [('The', 'DT'), ('cat', 'NN'), ('sat', 'VBD'), ('on', 'IN'), ('the','DT'), ('mat','NN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('dog', 'NN'), ('chewed', 'VBD')]

gram = r"""chk: {<DT>?<NN><VBD>}"""
```

I ll get:

```
the cat sat 

the dog chewed
```

But if I am looking for information about a specific word like cat.
Is there a way to chunk specificaly the word cat insted its tagging
just like bellow?

```
r"""chk: {<DT>?<cat><VBD>}"""
```

Comment: A simple bypass I guess would be to assign your word of interest its own pos-tag (think there is the option with most NLTK taggers to override the tag assigned with custom tags), then write an extra grammar rule containing your custom pos-tag in there...

Comment: So far this is what I'm doing to make this work. But would be simpler if I could change whenever I want the tag for word.